# Finding what function is causing a library function to be linked

Tags: c++, linker, embedded

I am working on an embedded system using c++ with a modified gcc tool-chain, and sprintf is in my final executable as are a large number of support functions (_svfiprintf_r,_sprintf_r,_svfprintf_r), even though I have not explicitly referenced them in my code.

I think these functions are making my executable far too large for my system. Is there an efficient way to get the linker to tell me why (what function calls) a given function is linked?

The toolchain is GNU tools for Xilinx Micoblaze.

Comment: A linker wouldn't help you much with that. What you'd want is a call-graph/static analysis tool, or in the worst case ack (a grep for code)

Comment: Check your compiler/project build options for generating a map file.  Make sure the option is turned on and then rebuild.  The map file should tell you  how much memory is being allocated for each function, either directly or indirectly.

Comment: Are you explicitly calling `sprintf` or is that one of the functions you are trying to determine where it is referenced from?  Some toolchains can generate call trees as linker output - what toolchain are you using?

Comment: @Clifford, I was unclear in my original post. I am not calling sprintf anywhere in my code nor printf or any related (as far as i can tell) function. I do not have a serial port or log so all text based functionality is useless to me.

Comment: Some library you are linking perhaps?  Although it is part of stdio, sprintf() is really a string handling function rather than I/O function. You have not answered my question about your toolchain; the answer to that is required to  to answer your question.

Comment: @Clifford Its the Xilinx micoblaze tool chain which seems to be a modified gcc chain. I think I have determined that it is included by the dynamic memory system which I was using out of laziness, but it would still be nice to have a way to determine that in the future.

Comment: You should use the comments to improve the question rather than place relevant information in comments.

Answer (score 2):

The GNU linker option `--cref` will list all object modules a symbol is referenced from (to the map file or to stdout) - that may help track down hidden usage within libraries.

---

The `sprintf` function itself is likely very small, and is implemented in terms of these underlying functions - you cannot avoid the "support" functions if you use `sprintf` - they are what do the work. The `sprintf` function in total is not a trivial function, and if code size is critical, standard library formatted I/O in general should be avoided altogether.

Some libraries support reduced-size stdio implementations that remove support for floating-point formatting which is particularly expensive.

The `_r` suffix denotes reentrant library implementations.  In the reentrant versions, each thread may have its own copy of `errno` which then becomes a thread-local variable rather than a global.  These `_r` functions have little overhead. And if you are not running in a multi-threaded environment they may have no overhead at all other than an additional function call.

The `f` in the prefix simply indicates a "file I/O" function, but in reality refers to any "stream I/O" operation - the buffer supplied to your `sprintf` call is treated as an output stream by the lower level functions.

The `v` in the prefix indicates a version of the function that takes a `va_list` argument and is required to translate the higher level variadic function into a regular function to process the variable length argument list.

The `i` in the prefix indicates an *integer-only* implementation, so it appears that you have already elected to remove floating-point support?

So in this case I would guess that the call chain is `sprintf` -> `_sprintf_r` -> `_svfprintf_r` -> `_svfiprintf_r`.

It is also likely that the leaf function `_svfiprintf_r` is where all the work is done, and the others are thin wrappers that do little more than pass on the call.

The important thing to realise is if `sprintf` were entirely self contained and if it did not utilise these "support functions", it would itself be very large.  Moreover there is a great deal of common code amongst the various formatted I/O functions and if they were all self contained your code would increase significantly in size for each function you used.  Once you have used `sprintf` for example, adding `printf` should be relatively inexpensive since they share much of the same underlying code.

If you really cannot accept the overhead of the standard library implementation of formatted I/O, you might consider using an alternative lightweight implementation such as [Spare Time Labs' Tiny printf](http://www.sparetimelabs.com/tinyprintf/tinyprintf.php) which provides small cut-down implementations of `sprintf` and `printf`.  Interestingly in this you can see a similar structure where both functions are themselves very small but share a common larger implementation in `tfp_format`.

Comment: Sorry, I was not clear. I don't want any printf functionality, I have no terminal to output printf to, no log to log to, no textual interface of any kind.